# Changing complexity from O(n) to O(1)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

For the following code :

```
 s = 0 ;  
 for(i=m ; i<=(2*n-1) ; i+=m)  {  
      if(i<=n+1){ 
        s+=(i-1)/2 ; 
      }  
      else{ 
        s+=(2*n-i+1)/2 ; 
      }    
 }
```

I want to change the complexity of the code from `O(n)`
to `O(1)` . So I wanted to eliminate the for loop . But as
the sum `s` stores values like `(i-1)/2` or `(2*n-i+1)/2` so eliminating the loop involves tedious calculation of floor value of each  `(i-1)/2` or `(2*n-i+1)/2` . It became very difficult for me to do so as I might have derived the wrong formula in sums of floors . Can u please help me in Changing complexity from `O(n)` to `O(1)`. Or please help me with this floor summations . Is there any other way to reduce the complexity ? If yes ... then how ?

Comment: you can tell if you made a mistake by checking against the results.

Comment: What technique are you using to eliminate the loop?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being modded down so much.  This seems like a very tricky problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Don Roby said, there is a plain old arithmetic solution to your problem. Let me show you how to do it for the first values of i.

*** EDIT 2 : CODE FOR THE LOWER PART ***

```
    for(int i=m ; i<= n+1 ; i+=m)//old computation
          s+=(i-1)/2 ;


    int a = (n+1)/m; // maximum value of i
    int b = (a*(a+1))/2; //
    int v = 0;
    int p;
    if(m % 2 == 0){
        p = m/2;
        v = b*p-a; // this term is always here
    }
    else{
        p = (m - 1)/2;
        int sum1 = ((a/2)*(a/2 +1))/2; 
        int sum2 =  (((a-1)/2)*((a-1)/2 +1))/2;  

        v = b*p -a ;// this term is always here
        v+= sum1 + a/2; //sum( 1 <= j <= a )(j-1), j pair
        v+= sum2; //sum( 1 <= j <= a )(j-1), j impair
    }
    System.out.println( " Are both result equals ? "+ (s == v));
```

How do I come up with it? I take

```
 for(i=m ; i<= n+1 ; i+=m)
      s+=(i-1)/2 ;
```

I make a change

```
 for(j=1 ; j*m <= n-1 ; j++)
     s+=(j*m-1)/2 ;
```

I pose `a=Math.floor(n+1/m)`. There are 3 cases :

1. m is pair, then interior of the loop is `s+= p*j`. The result is

   ```
    b(a*(a+1))/2 -a
   ```
2. m is impair and the iterator j is pair
3. m is impair and the iterator j is impair
   When m is impair, you can write `m = 2p + 1` and the interior of the loop becomes

   ```
    s+= p*j + (j-1)/2
   ```

`p*j` is the same as before, now you need to break the division by assuming j is always pair or j always impair and summing both values.

The next loop you need to compute is

```
 for(int i=a+1 ; i<= (2*n-1) ; i+=m)// a is (n+1)/m
    s+=(2*n-i+1)/2;
```

which is the same as

```
 for(int i=1 ; i<= (2*n-1)-a ; i+=m)
    s+= (2n-a)/2 - (i-1)/2;
```

This loop is similar to the first one, so there is not much work to do...
Indeed this is tedious..

Answer (score 2):

My approach to this would be to first write characterizing tests asserting the values produced for different values of `m` and `n`, and then start refactoring.

Your main loop has a change of logic based on getting halfway through (the `if(i<=n+1)` choice), so I'd first split it into two loops based on that.

Then you have in each of the resulting loops, a computation that varies principally on whether `i` is even or odd.  Split each into 2 more loops separating thes, and the floor computations may be simpler to understand.  Alternatively, you might see a pattern of repeated values that lets you simplify these loops in a different way.

Each of the resulting loops will likely be something resembling a sum of an arithmetic progression, so you'll likely find that they can be replaced by closed form computations not requiring loops at all.

While you go along this path, you might also refactor to extract portions of the computation to functions.  Write characterizing tests for these as you extract them.

Keep running all your tests as you proceed and you'll likely be able to reduce this to a sum of simple computations, which might then reduce further by plain old arithmetic.